# ASP.NET WebForms Routing

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-webforms, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет.

В проекте ASP.NET WebForms использую стандартный Routing. Определяю маршруты, указываю, на какие страницы они отражаются.

Например, в следующем примере задан маршрут, который при запросе URL вида ***http://мойсайт.ru/content*** за кулисами предаст управление странице **Index.aspx**, которая расположена в папке **Contents**.

```
 private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection route)
 {
       route.RouteExistingFiles = true;

       route.MapPageRoute("MyRoute", "content", 
            "~/Contents/Index.aspx");
 }
```

Собственно, все это хорошо работает, но не нравится то, что я могу обратиться к странице ***http://мойсайт.ru/contents/Index.aspx*** еще и напрямую, а не только через маршрут. Можно ли как-то отключить это, т.е. чтобы **все обращение** к страницам **происходили через систему маршрутизации**, а напрямую вызвать страницы было нельзя.

**Обновление**

Я думаю, через конфигурацию маршрутов такое не сделать, судя по моему опыту работы с маршрутами в MVC. В идеале я хочу добиться следующего. Например, пользователь напрямую запрашивает страницу http://мойсайт.ru/contents/Index.aspx, т.к. для данной страницы существует маршрут, то сервер переадресовывает (если здесь уместно данное слово) браузер пользователя на http://мойсайт.ru/content. И в итоге пользователь в адресной строке своего браузера видит уже http://мойсайт.ru/content, несмотря на то, что он запрашивал страницу напрямую. Думаю, идея ясна.

Comment: Хм. А почему бы не зараутить на 404 всё, что заканчивается на `.aspx`? (Если такое возможно.)

Answer (score 1):

Вот готовый пример:

Класс для перезаписи адресов

```
using System;
namespace Aisha
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        #region ToTranslit

        public static string ToTranslit(this string text)
        {
            string translet = text.Replace("й", "j").
            Replace("Й", "J").Replace("С++", "C_plus_plus").
            Replace("ц", "c").Replace("Ц", "C").
            Replace("у", "u").Replace("У", "U").
            Replace("к", "k").Replace("К", "K").
            Replace("е", "e").Replace("Е", "E").
            Replace("н", "n").Replace("Н", "N").
            Replace("г", "g").Replace("Г", "G").
            Replace("ш", "sh").Replace("Ш", "Sh").
            Replace("щ", "sch").Replace("Щ", "Sch").
            Replace("з", "z").Replace("З", "Z").
            Replace("х", "h").Replace("Х", "X").
            Replace("ъ", "j").Replace("Ъ", "J").
            Replace("ф", "f").Replace("Ф", "F").
            Replace("ы", "i").Replace("Ы", "I").
            Replace("в", "v").Replace("В", "V").
            Replace("а", "a").Replace("А", "A").
            Replace("п", "p").Replace("П", "P").
            Replace("р", "r").Replace("Р", "R").
            Replace("о", "o").Replace("О", "O").
            Replace("л", "l").Replace("Л", "L").
            Replace("д", "d").Replace("Д", "D").
            Replace("ж", "gh").Replace("Ж", "Gh").
            Replace("э", "e").Replace("Э", "E").
            Replace("я", "yu").Replace("Я", "Yu").
            Replace("ч", "ch").Replace("Ч", "Ch").
            Replace("с", "s").Replace("С", "S").
            Replace("м", "m").Replace("М", "M").
            Replace("и", "i").Replace("И", "I").
            Replace("т", "t").Replace("Т", "T").
            Replace("ь", string.Empty).Replace("Ь", string.Empty).
            Replace("б", "b").Replace("Б", "B").
            Replace("ю", "yu").Replace("Ю", "Yu").
            Replace("ё", "e").Replace("Ё", "E").
            Replace("`", string.Empty).Replace("!", string.Empty).
            Replace("$", string.Empty).Replace("%", string.Empty).
            Replace("^", string.Empty).Replace("&", string.Empty).
            Replace("*", string.Empty).Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).
            Replace("-", "_").Replace("=", "_ravno").Replace("+", "_plus").
            Replace("~", string.Empty).Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).
            Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty).
            Replace(":", string.Empty).Replace(";", string.Empty).
            Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).
            Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace("<", string.Empty).Replace(">", string.Empty).
            Replace(",", string.Empty).Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty).
            Replace("?", string.Empty).Replace(" ", "_").Replace("C#", "CSharp");
            return translet;
        }

        public static string GetUrl(string url, object id)
        {
            return GetUrl(url, id, null);
        }

        public static string GetUrl(string url, object id, object title)
        {
            if (title != null)
            {
                if (title.ToString().Length > 200)
                {
                    return string.Format("/{0}/{1}-{2}", url, title.ToString().Remove(200).ToTranslit(), id);
                }

                return string.Format("/{0}/{1}-{2}", url, title.ToString().ToTranslit(), id);
            }

            return string.Format("/{0}/{1}", url, id);
        }
        public static string GetUrlPr(string url, object id)
        {
            return GetUrlPr(url, id, null);
        }
```

Далее global

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
<script RunAt="server">
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("steelSpark", "steelSpark/{id}", "~/steelSpark/View.aspx");
    } 
</script>
```

И web config

```
<system.webServer>
    <!--Для подключения библиотеки Routing-->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Пример == [http://admamr.ru/steelSpark/129](http://xn----7sbab9byagn3e.xn--p1ai/steelSpark/129)